# C# create an excel file from my own XML file

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I have coded a program that queries from the database and creates an xml file that contains the query results. How do I make a macro enabled excel file that contains the elements from the xml file?

Here is a short sample of the xml file which is located at my drive C: (I replaced some parts with XXXX)

```
<JobSvc environment="TEST" dateTo="6/22/2015" dateFrom="2015-06-15T00:00:00+08:00">
  <process server="XXXX" type="XXXX" name="XXXX">
    <processId duration="2421" eventTime="6/1/2015 11:41:26 AM" source="TEST SOURCE" num="3">PROCESS ID</processId>
  </process>
</JobSvc>
```

Here is my attempt in generating the excel file from the xml file (I got it from the internet and unfortunately, it does not work but it also doesn't produce exceptions or errors because my program creates logs for exceptions..):

```
public void xmlToExcel()
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\PerformanceMonitorXML " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                }
            }
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C\\PerformanceMonitorExcel " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);



        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem was with Your privileges. If You want to save on C, You have to run VS with admin privileges. Also there was a typo in save as. Also I suggest writing into excel not cell by cell, but in object array. That code below worked for me>

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
XmlReader xmlFile;
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\example.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
object[,] objects = new object[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        objects[i, j] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
}
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "D3");
range.Value = objects;
releaseObject(range);
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\PerformanceMonitorExcel " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
releaseObject(xlApp);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
MessageBox.Show("finished");
```

The example xml was>

```
<root>
  <JobSvc environment="TEST" dateTo="6/22/2015" dateFrom="2015-06-15T00:00:00+08:00">
    <process server="XXXX" type="XXXX" name="XXXX">
      <processId duration="2421" eventTime="6/1/2015 11:41:26 AM" source="TEST SOURCE" num="3">PROCESS ID</processId>
    </process>
  </JobSvc>
  <JobSvc environment="TEST" dateTo="6/23/2015" dateFrom="2015-06-15T00:00:00+08:00">
    <process server="XXXX" type="XXXX" name="XXXX">
      <processId duration="2421" eventTime="6/1/2015 11:41:26 AM" source="TEST SOURCE" num="3">PROCESS ID</processId>
    </process>
  </JobSvc>
  <JobSvc environment="TEST" dateTo="6/24/2015" dateFrom="2015-06-15T00:00:00+08:00">
    <process server="XXXX" type="XXXX" name="XXXX">
      <processId duration="2421" eventTime="6/1/2015 11:41:26 AM" source="TEST SOURCE" num="3">PROCESS ID</processId>
    </process>
  </JobSvc>
</root>
```

Br, Márton

Comment: I got this exception:
`System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\PerformanceMonitorXML 06_07_2015.xml' because it is being used by another process. `

by the way, I'm running this code on a windows service, and the exception above was created by my log creator... I  dont have the file open and I don't know why it gives me that exception.

Comment: and when I open task manager, there are multiple instances of EXCEL.exe *32

Comment: Maybe the credentials of read are not set correctly? Try [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create(v=vs.110).aspx) the credentials part setting. The problem now is not with the excel writing than.

Comment: Shut down those excels in processes. They may lock the file. If there is an exception somewhere, there will be a frozen process locking the files.

Comment: it gives this error `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` at line 59 which is the saveAs line.. did your code work on your pc? howww

Comment: Update: It now works, I just replaced SaveAs with SaveCopyAs(). One more question though, for what purpose is your code 
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "D3");
range.Value = objects;
releaseObject(range);
`

Comment: Nice. The whole interop thing uses those dynamic objects. One of them is  the table's cells from A1 to D3 (that's a range). You have to modify the range to cover the generated table. Every dynamic object You have to free up. That's the boilerplate about `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = ` and `releaseObject(range);`. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "D3");` is similar to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1", "D3"];` or `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:D3"];`.